# Read/write appSettings keys from custom path in c#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

In my WPF application I've defined a custom appSettings using the `file` property in my app.config file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="%AppData%/MyFancyAppDir/Settings/settings.config"/>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>
 <!-- other non relevant to this question stuff -->
</configuration>
```

Now I want to save some configuration keys (in this case I want to track some file that need to be loaded depending on some logic), so I wrote these two methods,

The reader method

```
/// <summary>
/// Get desired key.
/// </summary>
public static T GetSettingFromKey<T>(string key, T defaultValue)
{
    var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
    if (settings != null)
    {
        var stringValue = ((NameValueCollection)settings)[key];
        if (stringValue != null) return (T)Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, typeof(T));
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

The writer method

```
/// <summary>
/// save or update key
/// </summary>
public static bool SaveSetting<T>(string key, T insertedValue)
{
    try
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.Contains(key))
            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = $"{insertedValue}";
        else
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, $"{insertedValue}");
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

My issue is that instead of writing in the specified `settings.config` file they are still updating the `MyFancyApp.exe.conf` file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered trying to write directly to the settings file as xml? It wouldn't surprise me in the slightest if the save functionality had no connection to the loading of external files

Comment: I would recommend ConfigurationBuilder class which allows to add, remove, update keys over multiple configuration files.

Comment: So it is impossible to use the standard ConfigurationManager class? Then what is the use for the file property in the app.config? Looks like there must be some way to interact with the custom file....